# Cloud Pub/Sub to BigQuery through Dataflow SQL query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I was following the linked [google cloud tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/samples/join-streaming-data-with-sql) to export the messages published to Pub/Sub to BigQuery through Dataflow SQL. In the tutorial, the message published is a JSON object and a schema is defined in Pub/Sub accordingly which is then exported into BigQuery through Dataflow SQL. Where this differs from my implementation is that the messages published on my Pub/Sub topic are an indefinite number of the same JSON object in a sort of array. An example would be:

`{{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":'a'}, {"name":"Mike", "age":28, "car":'b'}, {"name":"Adam", "age":33, "car":'b'}}`

In the above example, there are three similar JSON objects repeated but it could be any number.

My question would be, how do I go about defining a schema for this in Pub/Sub and is it possible to iterate through the JSON with an indefinite number of similar JSON objects repeated and export it into BigQuery?

Comment: If you set a JSON schema in PubSub, your message must enforce them. If your messages aren't JSON, but a string similar to JSON, you can't use a Dataflow SQL, because you MUST know the input format when you start your pipeline.

Comment: Can I use Dataflow SQL if the messages are an array of JSON objects of an uncertain number or the message should be one JSON object?

Comment: An array is always an uncertain size! You just need to have a valid JSON with a valid schema